# Prove the set A=B if their union= their intersection.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If I was given 2 sets A , B and the fact that their union = their intersection, how can I prove that two sets A and B are equal ? I tried using De Morgan’s law but i can’t get to their equality. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: To show $A=B$, show $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner how can i show that A is subset of B if i only have the fact that their union = their intersection ?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Would it not be more proper to say that $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$? Some people take $A\subset B$ to mean that $A$ is a _proper_ subset of $B$, i.e. $A$ is a subset not equal to $B$.

Comment: @Brian:  there are different [notational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset#%E2%8A%82_and_%E2%8A%83_symbols) conventions, but I edited my comment and answer to conform with yours

Comment: spelling edited;  *their* is a possessive pronoun; *there* is an adverb

Comment: @J.W.Tanner One notational convention aligns entirely with the much more universal $\leq, <$ convention, which is an objective reason to pick that one. The other convention uses the very ugly symbol $\subsetneq$, which is a subjective reason not to pick that one. That's my two cents on the matter. But using $\subset, \subsetneq$ isn't _wrong_. For the time being.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x\in A$, then $x\in A\cup B=A\cap B$, so $x\in B$; therefore $A\subseteq B$.

Now can you show $B\subseteq A$ to complete the proof $A=B$?

Comment: Thank u so much!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If one set contains an element that is not present in another, that element is present in the union, *but* not in the intersection.

Answer (score 0):

The intersection of two sets contains all elements that belong to both sets. The union of two sets contains all elements that belong to either set. If the union and intersection are identical, then all elements that belong to one set belong to the other one, too. There are no elements that belong to only one set or the other, therefore, the sets are the same.